# PostgreSQL query takes 100x longer when I make the WHERE clauses more restrictive, counterintuitively

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL query that's taking more than 15 seconds. When I change some of the values in the WHERE clauses, the query goes over 100x faster, even though the changes *broaden* the scope of the query.

Query #1 takes 15.2 **seconds**: `SELECT p.category_id, count(*) FROM cr JOIN p ON p_id = p.id WHERE p.category_id = 48 AND cr.created_date > '2019-08-23 21:00:00 +0000' GROUP BY p.category_id;`

Query #2 takes 44 **milliseconds**: `SELECT p.category_id, count(*) FROM cr JOIN p ON p_id = p.id WHERE p.category_id = 48 AND cr.created_date > '2017-08-23 21:00:00 +0000' GROUP BY p.category_id;` The only change is to `created_date`, where I've included two more years worth of `cr` rows, yet the query is super fast.

Query #3 takes 292 **milliseconds**: `SELECT p.category_id, count(*) FROM cr JOIN p ON p_id = p.id WHERE p.category_id < 49 AND cr.created_date > '2019-08-23 21:00:00 +0000' GROUP BY p.category_id;`. The only change from query #1 is to `category_id`, where I've included 47 more possible ids (1-48 instead of just 48), yet the query is still far faster than the original.

I'm at a loss. Queries #2 and #3 should be much more time-consuming, but it's only the first one that takes a long time.

**Edit**:

Here's the output when I do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...` with query #1:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=289.67..301.73 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=19075.641..19075.642 rows=1 loops=1)
  Group Key: p.category_id
  Buffers: shared hit=606998
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=289.67..301.71 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=10.354..19069.554 rows=14609 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=606998
        ->  Index Scan using _idx_category_id on p  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.018..3.676 rows=2642 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (category_id = 48)
              Buffers: shared hit=544
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on cr  (cost=289.25..293.26 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=7.203..7.211 rows=6 loops=2642)
              Recheck Cond: ((p_id = p.id) AND (created_date > '2019-08-23 21:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
              Heap Blocks: exact=14591
              Buffers: shared hit=606454
              ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=289.25..289.25 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=7.199..7.199 rows=0 loops=2642)
                    Buffers: shared hit=591863
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cr_p_id_index  (cost=0.00..9.88 rows=193 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=6 loops=2642)
                          Index Cond: (p_id = p.id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=7981
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cr_created_date_index  (cost=0.00..276.71 rows=9637 width=0) (actual time=7.189..7.189 rows=79774 loops=2642)
                          Index Cond: (created_date > '2019-08-23 21:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                          Buffers: shared hit=583882
Planning time: 0.431 ms
Execution time: 19075.698 ms
```

And here it is for query #2:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=0.85..720.03 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=31.628..31.630 rows=1 loops=1)
  Group Key: p.category_id
  Buffers: shared hit=24780
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..719.92 rows=20 width=4) (actual time=0.024..27.561 rows=16281 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=24780
        ->  Index Scan using _idx_category_id on p  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.015..1.883 rows=2642 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (category_id = 48)
              Buffers: shared hit=544
        ->  Index Scan using cr_p_id_index on cr  (cost=0.43..709.55 rows=193 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.007 rows=6 loops=2642)
              Index Cond: (p_id = p.id)
              Filter: (created_date > '2017-08-23 21:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              Buffers: shared hit=24236
Planning time: 0.251 ms
Execution time: 31.663 ms
```

And here it is for query #3:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=52583.40..52583.67 rows=27 width=12) (actual time=389.141..389.150 rows=22 loops=1)
  Group Key: p.category_id
  Buffers: shared hit=89513, temp read=1187 written=1173
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=20169.93..52535.14 rows=9651 width=4) (actual time=235.938..363.334 rows=79992 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (cr.p_id = p.id)
        Buffers: shared hit=89513, temp read=1187 written=1173
        ->  Index Scan using cr_created_date_index on cr  (cost=0.43..30914.94 rows=9651 width=4) (actual time=0.010..50.387 rows=79992 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (created_date > '2019-08-23 21:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              Buffers: shared hit=78529
        ->  Hash  (cost=14955.75..14955.75 rows=317740 width=8) (actual time=235.394..235.394 rows=321138 loops=1)
              Buckets: 131072  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 2608kB
              Buffers: shared hit=10984, temp written=957
              ->  Seq Scan on p  (cost=0.00..14955.75 rows=317740 width=8) (actual time=0.010..127.499 rows=321138 loops=1)
                    Filter: (category_id < 49)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 3
                    Buffers: shared hit=10984
Planning time: 0.241 ms
Execution time: 389.209 ms
```

Comment: Can you please include the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT...` for your three queries?

Comment: @Jeremy I added them.

Comment: @Zach I have checked `explain` results of your query, easy thing you need to do is add appropriate index and batch processing as I suggested in my answer. Try to create `composite index` as you have used multiple columns in where clause.

Comment: @Zach I could see result returned is large. So please try to update default value of `work_mem` of postgres from `4MB` to `8MB`, so it will fasten your query processing by utilise 8MB for get large data, otherwise it can use only `4MB` leads increase processing time. You can update work_mem based on you machine configuration and other needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ->  Index Scan using _idx_category_id on p  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.015..1.883 rows=2642 loops=1)
> ```

When the estimated number of rows is off by a factor of 2642, bad plans will happen.

If you ANALYZE the table (`ANALYZE P;`), does that fix the problem?  If so, then you have to wonder why the autovacuum system was not doing an autoanalyze on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons you see this difference. Following are few example.

1. If you run the same query more than one time then there is a possibility result will be given from **cache**. So please do slight change (at least in add/remove few seconds in date value used in query) in query and check.
2. Number of matching rows will increase the time taken.

You can check the performance by `explain` method in postgres. It will return appropriate result, you need compare cost return by this explain method. This is the **best way to compare query results**.

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-explain.html

You can improve the query by following ways very soon.

1. Add appropriate index based on column type (`date, string`) and operator (`=, like, ~=`) you have used. Postgres have different indexes, you can use those based on situation. If you want to use date type column in index then use `brin` index which is specially intended for date related querying. If you want to check `equality` the or `like` then use `btree` index. If you did not add index then it will search whole table when you querying. When you adding index it will fasten by search based on appropriate index.
2. Try to use batch processing. Get specific no of rows (1000 rows) at same time instead of loading all records at same time. If you load all records at same time 
   then it will create memory related issue and it will take much time to load all  data.
3. Increase your postgres default configuration like suggested in following page based on your machine configuration. It will also help you to improve the performance.

https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/